# Sort table by parameter (Reporting Services 2008)

Tags: sorting, reporting-services, parameters

In Reporting Services 2008, I would like to sort a table by the use of a parameter.
The table has fields MainCategory and SubCategory. My parameter is called SortCriterion and has two labels, "Main Category" and "Sub Category".
The sortexpression of the table should then be

```
=Parameters!SortCriterion.Value
```

But I do not know what to insert as value for the parameters. Naively, I tried

```
Fields!MainCategory.Value
```

and

```
Fields!SubCategory.Value
```

but it doesn´t work. Is it possible and how?

Comment: Are you looking to allow the user to specify which columns to sort on based on parameter values? Since a parameter value wouldn't change, I can't understand how you'd sort on it another way, unless you mean filter perhaps?

Comment: Yes, the user may specify by which column the table should be sorted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the Sort Expression of the table to:

```
=IIF(Parameters!SortCriterion.Value = "Main Category",
  Fields!MainCategory.Value,
  Fields!SubCategory.Value)
```

If this doesn't give you the results you want then please give an example of what sorting you are after.